# Calculating uncertinity in measurements

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I have a question relating to uncertinity.The equation used is period of a pendulum.

T=2π √(l/g)

For example consider time to complete 10 cycles by the pendulum as 19.6 (+/- 0.2)s.
I want to know how to calculate the **uncertinity** of

1.period (T)

2.T^2

3.log T

Any help would be appriciated :)

Comment: Hi SriniShine, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Asking for answers to your homework questions is not allowed by our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714), but if you edit it to focus on the specific concept that is giving you trouble, it could be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Given $X = f(A,B,C,\ldots)$ where $f$ is some function, the error in $X$ is given by

$$(\Delta X)^2= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}\cdot\Delta A\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\cdot\Delta B\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\cdot\Delta C\right)^2 + \cdots$$

where $\Delta i$ is the error in $i$.

So the period is given by

$$T = \frac{t}{n}$$

Where $t$ is the total time, and $n$ is the number of trials. So,

$$(\Delta T)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\Delta t\right)^2+ 0$$

because $\Delta n$ is $0$.

Then apply same method to further functions of $t$ and $n$.

Comment: You should check your error propagation formula. It's supposed to be the quadrature sum of those terms, not the linear sum.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: If you rephrase the question so it is more generally about error propagation it could be reopened.